# (open generic type) typeof generic type with no parameters specified

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Can somebody explain me the need in C# language for `typeof(SomeGenericType<>`), with no concrete parameters specified.

I put together the following example:

```
        var t1 = typeof(Nullable<>);
        var t2 = typeof(Nullable<int>);
        var q = 1 as int?;

        var b1 = t1.IsInstanceOfType(q); //false
        var b2 = t2.IsInstanceOfType(q); //true
```

I first thought `typeof(Nullable<>)` is "more generic" than `t2`, which specifies generic parameter `int`, but `b1` turns out to be  `false` - so instance of `int?` is not instance of `Nullable<>`.

So how a variable should be defined for `b1` to be `true`? what practical uses does it have?

Comment: “X is more generic than Y” isn’t synonymous with “Y is an instance of X”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So how a variable should be defined for b1 to be true?

It can't. (In fact, with `Nullable<T>` you'll run into interesting boxing problems anyway, but there we go...)

At execution time, values are always instances of *closed* types. `Nullable<>`, `List<>` are *open* generic types. It's never useful to call `IsInstanceOfType` on such a type. That doesn't mean it's useless though.

Typically open types are used in reflection. For example:

```
public IList CreateList(Type elementType)
{
    Type closedType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(elementType);
    return (IList) Activator.CreateInstance(closedType);
}
```

There can be code high up which *is* generic, but calls into lower levels passing in `Type` values instead - the list could then go back up the stack and be cast to `IEnumerable<T>` for the appropriate value of `T`.

Likewise you may want to create a closed type with reflection to call a method on it, etc.

You can *also* use it to find out whether a particular type implements a generic interface for *some* type argument - for each interface implemented, you can find out if it's generic, get the generic type definition, and see whether that's equal to (say) `IEnumerable<>`.

Answer (score 4):

That's an *open generic type*.
It's not an actual type; it is not possible to have an instance of that type.

Instead, you can use it to generate a concrete (*closed*) generic type, such as `Nullable<int>`.

You can also check whether a closed generic type is an instance of a particular open generic type by checking its `GetGenericTypeDefinition()` method.

Comment: can you pls provide with a practical example of `open generic type`

Comment: @glaucus: A practical example of what exactly? `typeof(List<>)` is an example of an open generic type.